# Flurry (Android), how to log the time between user interactions?

Tags: android, flurry

I'm a bit surprised the documentation of Flurry-Android is so measly.
Let's take this example: your application has levels that users complete, how do you log the time that users take for each level to complete?

This is the basic API calls for events:

```
FlurryAgent.logEvent(String eventId, Map < String, String\> parameters, boolean timed)  
FlurryAgent.logEvent(String eventId, boolean timed)
```

Where should you put `levelindex` and how does the timing work? How will the data be presented?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `endTimedEvent`. In your example with logging the amount of time user takes to complete a level, you would do the following when the level starts:

```
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("index","1");
FlurryAgent.logEvent("PlayingLevel", params, true);
```

... and the following when the level ends:

```
FlurryAgent.endTimedEvent("PlayingLevel");
```

Answer (score 0):

Note: Flurry has documentation on how to record the duration of an event online. Look at the Tier 3 Events section for the example code.

http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/GettingStarted/Events/Android